# Canon CanoScan N640P ex driver for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, drivers, scanner

I would like to use my old CanoScan N640P ex scanner on my new OS. I have searched for drivers, but I have not found anything. Can you please offer me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hardware doesn't have a indefinite life-time; technology progresses, things get old, and the manufacturers stop supporting them, including making drivers for new OSs.

Contact Canon, and if they have no updated driver for you then it's time to buy a scanner that's compatible with your chosen OS.

Comment: But this scanner is working, and the functionality is enough for me.

Comment: Is it working with your current OS? If not, you either need to get a new one or run another OS.